# ASP.NET Core middleware handling SQL serialization failure retries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, isolation-level, asp.net-core-middleware

I am currently trying to write an ASP.NET Core API middleware which opens a SQL transaction before the underlying MVC action is executed. The transaction uses the Serializable isolation level, and is used by all SQL requests in the underlying MVC action. Then, when the MVC action exits:

- if it succeeded, the middleware should commit the transction ;
- if it failed with a serialization error, the middleware should reset everything and retry the MVC action (max. N times) ;
- otherwise, the middleware should roll back the transaction and rethrow the error.

What I ended up with is:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IDatabaseDriver databaseDriver)
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering(REQUEST_BUFFER_THRESHOLD);

    int attempt = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        attempt++;
        try
        {
            await this._next(context);
            await databaseDriver.Commit();
            break;
        }
        catch (PostgresException ex)
        when (ex.SqlState == PostgresErrorCodes.SerializationFailure &&
              attempt <= MAX_RETRIES)
        {
            // SQL serialization failure: rollback and retry
            await databaseDriver.Rollback();
            context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Unhandled error: rollback and throw
            await databaseDriver.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly because SQL serialization exeptions sometimes happen at the `await databaseDriver.Commit()` step, which is executed after the action returned successfully and started writing to the HTTP response stream. This results in duplicate JSON data in the response body.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

- Let the API client reexecute the query (use a dedicated error code like HTTP 419) and never reexecute the ASP.NET action from a middleware. Using request buffering is a bad thing anyway and there might be other undesirable side effects when rerunning the MVC pipeline.
- Commit the request transaction in each MVC action before it returns instead of doing so from the outer middleware.
- Commit the transaction in a global action filter (only if no exception is thrown), which is run before the response stream is touched, thus avoiding the duplicate "commit" instruction in each action from the previous approach.
- Somehow delay the ASP.NET MVC pipeline from writing to the response stream until the transaction is commited (is that even possible?).
- Anything else.

Comment: You should consider being careful with this approach to transaction handling - if one of your actions makes a call to an external API (for example), you will be waiting with an open transaction until that has completed - this could be a long time (in transaction land) and you may open yourself up to various deadlocking fun.

Comment: True enough. Although our API is consumed from a browser, so long requests are a problem to begin with. In our current implementation, calls to external APIs having a risk to take a long time (> 200 ms) are handled in separate services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by resetting the response stream before each retry. This is normally not possible because the response stream is not seekable, but you can use a temporary `MemoryStream` to replace the response stream while the middleware is running:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IDatabaseDriver databaseDriver)
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering(REQUEST_BUFFER_THRESHOLD);

    Stream originalResponseBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    using var buffer = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = buffer;

    try
    {
        int attempt = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            attempt++;
            try
            {
                // Process request then commit transaction
                await this._next(context);
                await databaseDriver.Commit();
                break;
            }
            catch (PostgresException ex)
            when (ex.SqlState == PostgresErrorCodes.SerializationFailure &&
                  attempt <= MAX_RETRIES)
            {
                // SQL serialization failure: rollback and retry
                await databaseDriver.Rollback();
                context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.Body.SetLength(0);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Unhandled error: rollback and throw
                await databaseDriver.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Response.Body = originalResponseBodyStream;
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await buffer.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
    }
}
```